# Pause JavaScript execution on alert box from Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: javascript

I am debugging a complex webpage which is throwing an alert box on clicking a particular element. I want to locate the code which is causing this. It is difficult to search my codebase by looking for message shown in alert box as it is very vague and dynamic. Is it possible to pause JS execution on alert in debugger from the Chrome dev tools or any other debugger? (In a similar way like Chrome allows to pause JS execution on events like click, etc).

I already tried reaching the code by pausing on click event, but there are too many JS files to step through and the code is minified and complex.

Thanks.

Comment: You know the button on whose click, it is triggered. Go to it and look for all reference where this button is used and check all handlers. You will find the code you are looking for.

Comment: That said, we do not recommend anything on SO, so any tools are out of picture. About pausing from dev tools, this can also be used on a public website to steal some code(*not that you will do*), at least I would refrain to go in that topic. So if it is your code, suggestion in above comment will help. Also if you are using any  IDE like *sublime/VS Code*, they have a search feature which can scan entire project. It may take sometime as you have pointed out that its a BIG project, but still, it should do for now.

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh. Will try this.

Comment: Besides the answer, a good approach is also to look for the element (button) in the dev tools and highlight it there. On the right side go to the Event Listener tab and unfold the click section. Here you find all the click listeners.

Answer (score 2):

You can override alert function, put a breakpoint and take a look at Call Stack to figure out where it comes from.

You will need to have browser's DevTools to be opened for `debugger;` to trigger. And ensure that this code is executed BEFORE actual alert that you are looking for is called, so put it at the top of everything else.

```js
(function() {
    var _old_alert = window.alert;
    window.alert = function() {
      // breakpoint
      debugger;
      _old_alert.apply(window, arguments);
    };
})();


alert('hey');
```